# Woo commerce State/Country list

Tags: wordpress, pdf, woocommerce

I am going to launch a website based on woo commerce and when I go on checkout page I found that the state/country has the city name in parentheses in thai language as shown in the picture below.

[image]

It is fine for us unless it does not show up correctly on PDF invoice file as shown in the picture.

[image]

Is there any way I can disable that or make it show up on PDF file correctly at least? Is there anything to do with encoding in plugin file?

PS. the pdf file I use extension name WooCommerce PDF Invoices & Packing Slips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you have any problem regarding the plugins functionality your must report/research in their specific plugin support forum.

For you,we have checked on there support forum and have 2 links to the resolved issue.Try [resolved issue 1](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/thai-language-boxed-characters?replies=13) and [resolved issue 2](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/accents-in-spanish-are-not-shown?replies=5) for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Well any issues Regarding State parentheses Language so you can use filter function ion function.php

```
<?php 
function add_my_states( $states ) {     
$states["ID"] = array( 'BA' => __('Bali', 'woocommerce') ,'JB' => __('Jawa Barat', 'woocommerce')); 
return $states; 
} 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_states', 'add_my_states', 10, 1 );
?>
```